# Updating textView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a textView set up on my main activity, and a button. When I click the button, I'd like the textView to start updating it's value based on the code below. However, this doesn't work and the problem is the loop. Can someone explain why? I am new to Java and Android Development

```
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.refView);
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            for(i=1;i<1;i++){
              i = i + 1;
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(i)+"hello");
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what *exactly* you want to happen. But, you can get rid of this line

```
i = i + 1;
```

because the `i++` already increments `i` by 1 with each iteration of the `for loop`.

Second, since `i` starts off at 1 and you want the `loop` to run while `i<1`, it will never enter the `loop`. It is never less than 1.

Third, if the conditions were different, say

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

it will run through the `loop` so fast that you won't even recognize a change.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I forgot the logic of the for loop and my code was pretty bad anyway aha. I fixed it, but since my loop is inside my OnClick, the loop runs through until the end and display the last value after exiting the OnClick rather than showing it changing live (I set the end condition to something large and incremented by fractional values so that I could watch it change). That's unfortunate - I'll have to figure out that now

Comment: That's because it is changing very quickly and the UI thread isn't waiting to show each one. Look at the postDelay method. There's a lot of posts on here about doing this. I'm on my phone so I'm not going to search for one right now but there are plenty of examples

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.refView);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int i = 0;
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                i = i + 1;
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(i)+"hello");
            }
        });
```

Your `for` loop conditions were wrong.
`for(i=1;i<1;i++)` won't even start, because `1<1` is already met.
Initiate count variable `i` before `onClick` and then update it before click and set new text with updated `i`.

Comment: Ah, such a simple error. I forgot the logic of the for loop. Thank you

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark "tick" near my answer. And to avoid simple problems in future, try "Rubber duck debugging" :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging